# How to check not in on multiple dataframes pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
d={'P':['A','B','C'],
   'Q':[5,6,7]
  }
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

d={'P':['A','C','D'],
   'Q':[5,7,8]
  }
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df1)

d={'P':['B','E','F'],
   'Q':[5,7,8]
  }
df3=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df3)
```

Code to check one dataframe column not present in other is this:

```
df.loc[~df['P'].isin(df1['P'])]
```

How to check the same in multiple columns?

How to find P column in df3 not in P column of df and df1?

Expected Output:

```
    P   Q
0   E   7
1   F   8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain 2 conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
cond1 = ~df3['P'].isin(df1['P'])
cond2 = ~df3['P'].isin(df['P'])
df = df3.loc[cond1 & cond2]
print (df)
   P  Q
1  E  7
2  F  8
```

Or join values of columns - by [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) or join list by `+`:

```
df = df3.loc[~df3['P'].isin(np.concatenate([df1['P'],df['P']]))]
#another solution 
#df = df3.loc[~df3['P'].isin(df1['P'].tolist() + df['P'].tolist())]
```

Comment: This is great answer as always. I would however put the conditions as variable cond1 cond2 for readability. Don’t you think?

Comment: @AntonvBR - Sure, I agree. ;)

Comment: @jezrael, you already kept the answer but as learning process i have Kept the my answer as well with using conditions little different way :-P , my +1

Answer (score 1):

What about, However jezrael already given expert answer :)

You can simply define the conditions, and then combine them logically, like:

```
con1 = df3['P'].isin(df['P'])
con2 = df3['P'].isin(df1['P'])
df = df3[~ (con1 | con2)]
>>> df
   P  Q
1  E  7
2  F  8
```

Comment: Your solution works, but IMO you should be careful with terminology. What exactly is `vector` in Pandas context? I think you mean Boolean series, but not sure.

Comment: @jpp, Yes Indeed,  In  this case, con1 and con2 are vectors of bools

Comment: @jpp, if you want to explain vectors in your own techniques then i can raise a new question in that regards :-)

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the term `vectors` in the Pandas documentation? Doesn't sound like a Python / Pandas term at all. You have `list`, `np.ndarray` [array], or `pd.Series` [series], but never `vector`.

Comment: @jpp, the one i went through sometimes back [Vectorization over Pandas series](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Comment: I see. So this is an interesting case where you've inferred a noun from a verb!

Comment: Can you explain more about last comment, i could not apprehend correctly? However, for the sake of confusion and debate over it i have rubbed that from my answer section!

Comment: `Vectorization` is derived from `vectorize` which is an **action** (also known as "verb"). You are using `vector` to indicate a thing / object (or **object type**), that's different.

Comment: Okay, So the link i referred and later inferred that i could not get correctly in my reading alas! i need to more agile as being a non-mathematical guy specially!
i'll revisit the section and vector theory to learn more about before giving this name in practical!